# How to change the center of a stereographic projection?

Tags: python, math, geometry, mapping, projection

Right now I am plotting a streographic projection with a center at the z axis by getting a P vector (Px, Py, Pz) from different directional indices in a unit sphere. The following process converts these to 2d coordinates.

```
(Python)
x2,y2,z2=P
theta2=np.arccos(abs(z2)/(x2**2+y2**2+z2**2)**.5)
phi2=np.arctan((y2/x2))
xp=theta2*np.cos((phi2))
yp=theta2*np.sin((phi2))
Plot xp,yp
```

What transformations do I apply in order to change the P vector (or a different aspect of the code) so that the center is on a different direction (x-axis for example)?

Thanks.

Comment: You might consider asking this question on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). While this question is programming-related and therefore on-topic here, it deals with math concepts so you might get better answers over there.

Comment: I did, no one answered on either. How can I get an answer?

Comment: It's also possible that you just happened to find a window in which no one was able to provide an answer. (It happens.) Give it a bit more time. If you still get no answers, see if there's a way you can clean up your question to make it easier to read, maybe pose the question in a different way. On the Mathematics board especially, post math notation with [LaTeX](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) instead of just pure code. They tend to like that more.